# HTTP 404 - Cannot pass url parameters to a flask route

Tags: python, http, flask

Any help with this is appreciated.

I am trying to pass a couple parameters to my Flask application in the URL query string.

This is my Flask code

```python
@application.route('/registeruser/', methods=['GET'])
def store_on_cloudant():
    qr = request.args.get('qr_code')
    fb_access_tok = request.args.get('fb_token')
    db.save({
        'qr': qr,
        'fb_access_tok': fb_access_tok

    })
    return
```

Here is the URL , I am using a GET because I am accessing the page in my browser

```
localhost:5000/registeruser/qr_code=qr12345&fb_token=token12345
```

I get an HTTP 404 error. Am I passing parameters correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing a question mark:

```
localhost:5000/registeruser/?qr_code=qr12345&fb_token=token12345
```

Without the question mark the parameters are part of the *URL path*, not the query parameters.

Comment: Its always the little things. Thanks so much! I really appreciate the help. I'll accept your answer when I can, in 15 minutes.